# Place order button not work (ReferenceError: review is not define) in magento

Tags: magento

I am working on Magento site which is hosting on Linux server but I am facing following issue:
**Problem:** When I click on place order button order will not proceed and in console, it give ReferenceError: review is not define on Linux server.
**Magento Version:** 1.8.1.0.
Thanks

Comment: pls see this http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/48941/onepage-checkout-error-review-is-not-defined

Comment: thanks for reply, I tried this solution but no use. Please give another solution if you have...